# [Java libgdx Game]Switch from jave.net UDP to webrtc

Tags: java, udp, libgdx, webrtc

for an exam i have to make a real time multiplayer game with the framework libgdx.

For the net comunications we used the udp protocolfrom the java.net and the game works fine, however the html version of the lbgdx game doesn't support multithreading and java.net so the only solution is to switch from java.net to webrtc.

Where can i found example for integrate webrtc in our game?

There is an API for java to use webrtc for client and server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose one is a native Java and the other is a browser HTML,

If you choose WebRTC you're needed to incorporate the WebRTC native libraries and JNI wrapper (or reuse Android JNI wrapper). Huge task.

If you could switch to TCP then WebSocket is the most promising way.
(Many Java implementations, supported by all modern browsers)

Comment: The problem is that tcp could be too slow for a real time multiplayer game but if there isn't a way to use UDP i'll try websocket, thank you.